# Report browser crash to server

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to add a feature to my web app which may cause the browser to run out of memory and crash for computers low on RAM. Is there any way that I can report when this happens to the server to determine how many users this happens to?

**EDIT:**

The specific problem is that the amount of memory used scales with the amount the user is zoomed in. To cope with this we will limit how much users can zoom in. We have an idea of how much to limit it based on in-house tests, but we want to know if the browser tab crashes for any users after we release this.

We could reduce the memory consumption with zooming, but doing so would entail a tremendous amount of refactoring, and would probably have negative, and possibly unacceptable performance losses.

Note that this is not "we know this happens, but we want to know how much", and more of "we don't think this will happen, but we want to know if it does."

Comment: I came across this library the other day. I haven't tried it though: http://jsnlog.com/

Comment: That isn't exactly what I need. I need to know when the *browser* crashes, at which point javascript is no longer executing.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a bunch of profiling and optimisations. A webapp by itself really shouldn't be crashing users' browsers

Comment: A crash is outside the domain of what JavaScript can "know" about the nature of the browser.  If crashing is a possibility in your application, I encourage you to reconsider your application design. Web apps aren't meant to be powerhouses of processing, and regardless of the platform the application is built on a crash shouldn't be a feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to get this information. If a server stops receiving data (sent by a websocket or such) via something such as a crash it has no way of telling what caused the stop. Either a browser tab being purposefully closed or a crash.

You could potentially check speed of a loop and report it to the server - such as frame-rate in a requestAnimationFrame - and check for trends if you are a fall before a close - but this is laden with pitfalls and potentially adds work to the client that may only add to your intensive code.